# Movable tags within text using jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm attempting to create an editable text field with non-editable, yet draggable, elements.  The closest I've gotten is using jQuery sortable on a "contenteditable" div.  I've found working examples of this with images, but not with any other type of tag.

```
<div contenteditable="true" data-role="content" id="sortable">
  <div class="sortable">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OwriT5v.png">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis justo id elit ultrices quis ultricies ante lobortis. Fusce placerat, ante quis molestie elementum, erat mi porttitor augue, eget iaculis eros metus nec libero. Vivamus consectetur est enim. Donec a orci egestas lacus porttitor
    <span class="tag" contenteditable="false">I want to move this</span>
    venenatis volutpat ut sem. Proin aliquet urna elementum sem tempor quis luctus arcu faucibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
$("#sortable").children().each(){
  $(this).sortable({
    connectWidth:"#sortable"
  });
}
```

You can see my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/918smpc3/1/

Is it possible to get the span tag to move like the img tag with jQuery sortable, or is this impossible within jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appear to be syntax errors `.each(){` missing callback function `.each(function(index, element) {})`; missing closing parenthesis `)` at end of `.each(function(index, element) {})` . Also, try wrapping text within `#sortable` in `span` elements

js

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
$("#sortable").children().each(function() {
    $(this).sortable({
      connectWith:"#sortable"
    });
})
```

html

```
    <div contenteditable="true" data-role="content" id="sortable">
    <div class="sortable">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OwriT5v.png"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis justo id elit ultrices quis ultricies ante lobortis. Fusce placerat, ante quis molestie elementum, erat mi porttitor augue, eget iaculis eros metus nec libero. Vivamus consectetur est enim. Donec a orci egestas lacus porttitor</span> 
        <div class="tag" contenteditable="false">I want to move this</div> <span>venenatis volutpat ut sem. Proin aliquet urna elementum sem tempor quis luctus arcu faucibus.</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/918smpc3/2/

Comment: Ah, sorry for the poor code.  This still doesn't solve my problem though.  I would like to be able to drag the elements anywhere within the text.

Comment: @GretaGail _"This still doesn't solve my problem though. I would like to be able to drag the elements anywhere within the text. "_ Try wrapping each word within a `span` element